# How to bind a GridView to a list of videos in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a list of videos I want to bind to a GridView using XAML. I did that programmatically with the following code and it is working:

```
private async void pageRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    IList<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string> { ".avi", ".mkv", ".mp4" };
    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
    queryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
    queryOptions.IndexerOption = IndexerOption.UseIndexerWhenAvailable;

    StorageFileQueryResult videoFileQuery = KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> dataSource = await videoFileQuery.GetFilesAsync();

    videoGridView.ItemsSource = dataSource; //Yep, that works :)
}
```

Howevery, I'd like to have this binding in XAML. So I changed the XAML GridView and removed the last line of the aforementioned code:

```
<GridView x:Name="videoGridView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding dataSource}"/>
```

Only that now the GridView is empty.

What must I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make 2 changes. First, instead of last line of your posted code, write following

```
this.DataContext = dataSource;
```

Then change your `Grid` to this

```
<GridView x:Name="videoGridView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind to a source of type ObservableCollection < StorageFile > .